# How to get ClientResponse body as DataBuffer in WebClient.exchangeToMono Spring 5.3?

Tags: spring-webflux, httpresponse, spring-webclient

Before the deprecation of `WebClient.exchange` method I used to get ClientResponse body as `Flux<DataBuffer>` and manipulated it.

In Spring 5.3 the `exchange()` method is deprecated and I would like to change the implementation as recommended:

> @deprecated since 5.3 due to the possibility to leak memory and/or
> connections; please,
> use {@link #exchangeToMono(Function)}, {@link #exchangeToFlux(Function)};
> consider also using {@link #retrieve()} ...

Tried to do the same call in the lambda passed to `exchangeToMono`, but `clientResponse.bodyToFlux(DataBuffer::class.java)` always return an empty flux; other experiments (i.e. getting body as mono string) also could not help to get the body.

**What is the standard way to get the ClientResponse body in Spring 5.3 ?**

*I am looking for a low-level body representation: something like "data buffer", "byte array" or "input stream"; to avoid any kind of parsing/deserialisation.*

**Before Spring 5.3:**

```
webClient
    .method(GET)
    .uri("http://somewhere.com")
    .exchange()
    .flatMap { clientResponse ->
       val bodyRaw: Flux<DataBuffer> = clientResponse.bodyToFlux(DataBuffer::class.java) 
       // ^ body as expected
           
       // other operations
    }
```

**After Spring 5.3**

```
webClient
    .method(GET)
    .uri("http://somewhere.com")
    .exchangeToMono { clientResponse ->
       val bodyRaw: Flux<DataBuffer> = clientResponse.bodyToFlux(DataBuffer::class.java)
       // ^ always empty flux
           
       // other operations
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new `exchangeToMono` and `exchangeToFlux` methods expect the body to be decoded inside the callback. Check this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/25751) for details.

Looking at your example, probably you could use `retrieve`, that is safer alternative, with `bodyToFlux`

```
webClient
        .method(GET)
        .uri("http://somewhere.com")
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToFlux(DataBuffer.class)
```

or `toEntityFlux` if you need access to response details like headers and status

```
webClient
        .method(GET)
        .uri("http://somewhere.com")
        .retrieve()
        .toEntityFlux(DataBuffer.class)
```

**Handling errors**

Option 1. Use `onErrorResume` and handle `WebClientResponseException`

```
webClient
        .method(GET)
        .uri("http://somewhere.com")
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToFlux(DataBuffer.class)
        .onErrorResume(WebClientResponseException.class, ex -> {
            if (ex.getStatusCode().equals(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)) {
                // ignore 404 and return empty
                return Mono.empty();
            }

            return Mono.error(ex);
        });
```

Option 2. Use `onStatus` convenience method to get access to response.

```
webClient
        .method(GET)
        .uri("http://somewhere.com")
        .retrieve()
        .onStatus(status -> status.equals(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND), res -> {
            // ignore 404 and return empty
            return Mono.empty();
        })
        .bodyToFlux(DataBuffer.class)
```

Both methods could be used to deserialize error response [Getting the response body in error case with Spring WebClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71643036/getting-the-response-body-in-error-case-with-spring-webclient/71650789#71650789)

Comment: The problem with Entity is - it only works for 200 response. In case of error you have no access to headers and body to recover and create proper pass-through.

Comment: @dpedro there are multiple ways to get access to the response. Updated the answer with more details

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
.retrieve()
.toEntityFlux(DataBuffer.class)
.map(...)
```

Of course in this solution firstly a ResponseEntity is created by spring, and they you map it into another one, but I didn't find any better solution.