# Can't handle bad request using doOnError WebFlux

Tags: rest, validation, spring-webflux

I wanna send some DTO object to server. Server have "Valid" annotation, and when server getting not valid DTO, he should send validation errors and something like "HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST", but when I'm trying to send HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST doOnError just ignore it.

**POST-request from client**

```
                    BookDTO bookDTO = BookDTO
                            .builder()
                            .author(authorTf.getText())
                            .title(titleTf.getText())
                            .publishDate(LocalDate.parse(publishDateDp.getValue().toString()))
                            .owner(userAuthRepository.getUser().getLogin())
                            .fileData(file.readAllBytes())
                            .build();
                        webClient.post()
                                .uri(bookAdd)
                                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                                .bodyValue(bookDTO)
                                .retrieve()
                                .bodyToMono(Void.class)
                                .doOnError(exception -> log.error("Error on server - [{}]", exception.getMessage()))
                                .onErrorResume(WebClientResponseException.class, throwable -> {
                                    if (throwable.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST) {
                                        log.error("BAD_REQUEST!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!"); --My log doesn't contain this error, but server still has errors from bindingResult
                                        return Mono.empty();
                                    }

                                    return Mono.error(throwable);
                                })
                                .block();
```

**Server-part**

```
@PostMapping(value = "/add", consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
public HttpStatus savingBook(@RequestBody @Valid BookDTO bookDTO, BindingResult bindingResult) {
    List<FieldError> errors = bindingResult.getFieldErrors();
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        for (FieldError error : errors ) {
            log.info("Client post uncorrected data [{}]", error.getDefaultMessage());
        }
        return HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST;
    }else{libraryService.addingBookToDB(bookDTO);}
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Use the `onStatus` operator to handle different http statuses

Answer (score 0):

`doOnError` is a so-called side effect operation that could be used for instrumentation before onError signal is propagated downstream. (e.g. to log error).

To handle errors you could use `onErrorResume`. The example, the following code handles the `WebClientResponseException` and returns `Mono.empty` instead.

```
...
.retrieve()
.doOnError(ex -> log.error("Error on server: {}", ex.getMessage()))
.onErrorResume(WebClientResponseException.class, ex -> {
    if (ex.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST) {
        return Mono.empty();
    }

    return Mono.error(ex);
})
...
```

As an alternative as @Toerktumlare mentioned in his comment, in case you want to handle http status, you could use `onStatus` method of the `WebClient`

```
...
.retrieve()
.onStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST::equals, res -> Mono.empty())
...
```

**Update**

While working with `block` it's important to understand how reactive signals will be transformed.

- `onNext(T)` -> T in case of `Mono` and `List<T>` for `Flux`
- `onError` -> exception
- `onComplete` -> null, in case flow completes without `onNext`

Here is a full example using WireMock for tests

```
class WebClientErrorHandlingTest {
    private WireMockServer wireMockServer;

    @BeforeEach
    void init() {
        wireMockServer = new WireMockServer(wireMockConfig().dynamicPort());
        wireMockServer.start();
        WireMock.configureFor(wireMockServer.port());
    }

    @Test
    void test() {
        stubFor(post("/test")
                .willReturn(aResponse()
                        .withHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                        .withStatus(400)
                )
        );

        WebClient webClient = WebClient.create("http://localhost:" + wireMockServer.port());

        Mono<Void> request = webClient.post()
                .uri("/test")
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(Void.class)
                .doOnError(e -> log.error("Error on server - [{}]", e.getMessage()))
                .onErrorResume(WebClientResponseException.class, e -> {
                    if (e.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST) {
                        log.info("Ignoring error: {}", e.getMessage());
                        return Mono.empty();
                    }

                    return Mono.error(e);
                });

        Void response = request.block();

        assertNull(response);
    }
}
```

The `response` is null because we had just complete signal `Mono.empty()` that was transformed to null by applying `block`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @Alex. I tried first way but its doesn't working. I think it's because WebClientResponseException doesn't occur when server return HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST. How i can fix it ? I updated my post to better understand the problem.

Comment: please check the updated answer. hopefully it helps.

Comment: Also I would suggest to review server part. Not sure why you returning HttpStatus as a response. http status is a part of the http response anyway.  Use `ResponseEntity` instead and return proper http status.