# Making http request in the background after return when using Webflux?

Tags: java, spring-webflux, reactive-programming

I'm trying to handle the error in webflux, and the handling includes sending http request based on the error message from upstream to get the related info of error, and then operate in db with the request result.

This error handling takes a lot of time and is not related with my response, so I wanna return the upstream result immediately and run the error handling process in the background.

I have tried with following code

```
return MyProcess()
       .doOnSuccess(response -> logSuccess())
       .doOnError(e-> Mono.fromCallable(()->apnsCallback.handleError(e.getMessage()))
                          .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
                          .subscribe());
```

It returns the result of `MyProcess()` immediately, and `handleError()` is triggered in the background, that looks good, but the problem is that only the code before my http request is executed.

I have read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71647505/cant-handle-bad-request-using-doonerror-webflux) and tried with `onErrorResume`, all the code in `handleError()` is executed but my service doesn't return until the error handle complete.

Is there anyway that I can make the http request in the background with webflux?

PS: My handleError generally look like this:

```
log.info("Some start log");
SomeDBDao.update();
return webClient.post()
       .uri(someUrl)
       .header(someHeader)
       .body(Mono.just(myObj), myObj.class)
       .retrieve()
       .bodyToMono(String.class)
       .timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(10));
```

Comment: first of all there are som strange things in your code i need to ask about, subscribOn applies at subscribe time, and publish on applies when the code hits publishOn. Both of the schedulers you have added will make your code "non-reactive" so can you please motivate why you intentionally need these, because usually you use one or the other, and you only turn your code non-reactive in very specific cases. Second of all, why have you added `subscribe` when in reactive the its the caller (the client, e.g the webpage) that is the subscriber. So why are you subscribing to your own application.

Comment: @Toerktumlare 1. For the `publishOn` I was trying to switch the thread in another test and forgot to remove it. You are right, it's not required when there's `subscribeOn`. 2. I refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57566465/fire-and-forget-with-reactor) and actually `subscribe` makes the errorHandler get triggered (at least the code before http request is executed), if Mono.fromCallable() doesn't end with subscribe() nothing will happen for the error handler.

Comment: Your approach looks good to me and I don't understand the problem you are facing. What do you mean by “only the code before my http request is executed“? Which part is exactly that? Maybe you should share how `handleIOSError` looks like? If it's returning a `Mono`, then you should use `defer` instead of `fromCallable`.

Comment: I got this issue solved after trying @MartinTarjányi 's solution. When I'm using webclient to make the http call in `handleError` , it will return a `Mono` and since it is created too early before the subscription time, it will get executed outside the scope of the returned `Mono`.