# Spring Boot web Client

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, webclient, spring-webclient

I am having an issue with the web client.

I am trying to make a post request. The request is good. The thing is, if I add onStatus in order to handle http error codes, I am getting a NPE when calling bodyToMono. If I remove onStatus, I get the response.

we could take this as an example:

```
Employee createdEmployee = webClient.post()
        .uri("/employees")
        .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
        .body(Mono.just(empl), Employee.class)
        .retrieve()
 .onStatus(HttpStatus::isError, clientResponse -> {
          if (clientResponse.statusCode() == HttpStatus.resolve(402)) {
            return Mono.error(new Exception("402"));
          }
          log.error("Error endpoint with status code {}", clientResponse.statusCode());
          if (clientResponse.statusCode() == HttpStatus.resolve(500)) {
            return Mono.error(new Exception("500"));
          }
          if (clientResponse.statusCode() == HttpStatus.resolve(512)) {
            return Mono.error(new Exception("512"));
          }
          return Mono.error(new Exception("Error while processing request"));
        })
        .bodyToMono(Employee.class);
```

I wan to handle 4xx and 5xx errors including their specific subtypes (404,402) 500, 512

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting the response body in error case with Spring WebClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71643036/getting-the-response-body-in-error-case-with-spring-webclient)

Comment: bodyToMono give you Mono object, not Employee class. Please stay in the reactor environment if you use Mono or Flux otherwise you will experience an operational anomaly.

Answer (score 0):

Before `bodyToMono()` you can use `onStatus()`

```
.onStatus(httpStatus -> {
    return httpStatus.is4xxClientError(); // handle 4xx or use .is5xxServerError() or .value()
}, clientResponse -> Mono.error(new RuntimeException("custom exception")))
```

Another option is to use `ExchangeFilterFunction` and apply it to your webclient

```
ExchangeFilterFunction responseErrorHandler =
        ExchangeFilterFunction.ofResponseProcessor(clientResponse -> {
            clientResponse.statusCode(); // handle any status manually
            return Mono.just(clientResponse);
        });

WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder()
        .filter(responseErrorHandler)
```

Comment: The problem is that it generates an NPE exception

Comment: Are you sure you have posted your entire code? Seems there's something missing