# Get an underlying custom exception class in WebClientResponseException

Tags: java, spring-boot, exception, spring-webclient

When making a call to my Rest API's endpoint, I am taking into account that it may end up in an exception thrown.

For example, I've got an endpoint `GET /api/entity?name=${some_name}`. Suppose that there's no entity of name `XYZ`. In that case, when someone makes a request `GET /api/entity?name=XYZ`, my service will throw `EntityNotFoundException` - a custom exception class I've made.

This is how such request looks like:

```
public void apiCall() {
    webClient.method(HttpMethod.GET)
                .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder
                        .path("/api/entity")
                        .queryParam("name", "XYZ")
                        .build()
                ).retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(MyCustomClass.class)
                .block();
}
```

The above call will throw `WebClientResponseException`. All I really need is the *underlying* exception that is thrown in `EntityService` and is called `EntityNotFoundException`. How do I retrieve my custom exception?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by underlining exception. This is a client and it handles HTTP request/responses. Probably you mean that server throws `EntityNotFoundException` but it will be transformed into HTTP response (probably JSON) that you would need to handle in your client. Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/71650789/9068895 for details