# How to refactor the deprecated method .exchange()?

Tags: java, spring, webclient

I have next method that uses in AbstractWebClient. How can I refactor it to get rid of deprecated .exchange() and save availability to work in abstract way?

```html
    private ClientResponse executeRequest(WebClient.RequestHeadersSpec<?> spec,
                                          RequestContext requestContext,
                                          String requestBody) {
        logRequest(requestContext, requestBody);
        return spec
                .exchange()
                .blockOptional()
                .orElseThrow(() -> new InternalException(String.format("%s: can't extract response from method \"%s\"", externalServiceName, requestContext.getApiMethodName())));
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to refactor WebClient.exchange in Spring 5.3 WebFlux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71584519/how-to-refactor-webclient-exchange-in-spring-5-3-webflux)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `retrieve()` method as suggested in `exchange()` documentation something like below:

```
return 
spec.retrieve().bodyToMono(ClientResponse.class).blockOptional()
                .orElseThrow(() -> new InternalException(String.format("%s: can't extract response from method \"%s\"",
                        externalServiceName, requestContext.getApiMethodName())));
```

Comment: I don't think you can use `ClientResponse.class`, you need to provide some sort of concrete implementation for that interface. Is that implied in your answer?

Comment: .bodyToMono use class type for decoding purpose, we are not passing concrete class's implementation in it.  Hope that helps @zaf187